# body-parser: Erro al mostrar req.body

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy intentando pasar parametros POST con un XMLHttpReques de javascript y que lo capture una ruta de express de NodeJS. Pero tengo problemas para recibir los datos.

Mi archivo con la petición del formulario:

```
let botonPost;
botonPost.addEventListener('click', postmanPrueba);

function postmanPrueba () {

    let boton = event.target;

    let formPost = new FormData();
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    formPost.append('uno', '1');
    formPost.append('dos', '2');

    function success () {
        let res = this.responseText;
        console.log(res);
        let box = document.getElementById('mensajes');
        mensajes.innerHTML = res;
    }
    xhr.addEventListener('load', success);
    xhr.open('post', '/crear-orden');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(formPost);
}
```

Mi archivo de rutas:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


// Usos
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false, type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}));
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.raw());

router.post("/crear-orden", async (req, res) => {
    let post = req.body;
    console.log(post);
    res.send('POST: console.log');
});


module.exports = router;
```

Al imprimir el objeto que debería tener los parámetros (req.body) me aparece lo siguiente:

```
{
  '------WebKitFormBoundaryYQkM4htBVo0KjfVw\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"uno"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '1\r\n' +
    '------WebKitFormBoundaryYQkM4htBVo0KjfVw\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dos"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '2\r\n' +
    '------WebKitFormBoundaryYQkM4htBVo0KjfVw--\r\n'
}
```

Que me estoy saltano? Que puedo hacer, cambiar o arreglar?
De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedo ayudarte, espero que te sea de ayuda.

Estas haciendo un uso incorrecto al poner router.use, deberías de hacer una instancia de express y después usar esa instancia de express para implementar los cuerpos de solicitud en json, etc.

(En el ejemplo no está la librería bodyParser ya que express ya lo tiene integrado)

Ejemplo:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router(); 

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false, type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}));

 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(express.raw());

router.post("/crear-orden", async (req, res) => {
    let post = req.body;
    console.log(post);
    res.send('POST: console.log');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Saludos @jonasdamher, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
Igual me sigue imprimiendo un objeto muy raro cuando lo hago con Javascript puro.
Pero cuando lo hago con la herramienta PostMan lo hace perfectamente.